# Why does this var only select first element found?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select a specific parent of every element that has a title attribute that starts with "Mod" and put them in a single var that I can then easily control.

```
var allMods= $('#main-element .object[title^="Mod"]').closest('.specific-parent');
$(allMods).hide();
```

but it only works on the first found element, I can't understand how to set the var to be every match, can someone give me a hand please?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Well it is all what this function does, look: http://api.jquery.com/closest/
("get the first element")

Comment: You will need to post the html as well..

Comment: @JackL. notice the "***For each element in the set***" in the docs

Comment: @JackL. And what does it say immediately before that? "For each element in the set" - if you have multiple elements in the jQuery object you call `.closest()` on you can have more than one element in the object returned by it.

Comment: the find return multiple element see http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: (*also you do not need to do `$(allMods)` as it is already a jquery object. `allMods.hide()` should suffice*)

Comment: For the people that are saying `closest()` will only return 1 element, despite being passed an array of elements... http://jsfiddle.net/tU83M/

Comment: Without seeing your html no-one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work *provided* all of the `.object[title^="Mod"]` elements are within the `#main-element` container.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/exebapE/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/exebapE/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<div id="main-element">
  <div class="specific-parent">
    <div class="object" title="Mod1">Mod1 - turns green</div>
  </div>
  <div class="specific-parent">
    <div class="object" title="Mod2">Mod2 - turns green</div>
  </div>
  <div class="specific-parent">
    <div class="object" title="Mod3">Mod3 - turns green</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="specific-parent">
    <div class="object" title="Mod4">Mod4 - does <strong>not</strong> turn green</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#main-element .object[title^="Mod"]').closest(".specific-parent").css("color", "green");
```

Result: Only the `.specific-parents` of `.object[title^="Mod"]` elements that are within `#main-element` turn green.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the **first** element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

You probably want [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) (note the S, .parent() also returns only ONE element)

Comment: It will return the closest to `each element in the set`... http://jsfiddle.net/tU83M/

Comment: Yes, but that's on **YOUR** dom. The OP's got an entirely different selector set, and guaranteed a totally different DOM.

Comment: @MarcB: Maybe a different DOM, but there's no reason to assume the OP's selector set (including `closest`) won't result in multiple elements, see my answer. It's all about set theory with jQuery. :-)

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you're saying `closest()` is incorrect when it isn't.  Without seeing his DOM we can't say what's wrong.